# How to fit an ellipse around a polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, buffer, arcgis-10.4, ellipse

I'm using ArcMap to draw polygons around some geologic features. I want to know the length of the semi major and semi minor axes of the smallest ellipse that would fit around the polygons.

I'm a new Arc user, so it's possible that there's a simple way to do this, but not that I've yet found. Maybe the buffer tool could do the trick, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Did you want to create the ellipse manually or derive it from a tool automatically?

Comment: Automatically - I have the length and x-y coordinates of my polygons in the attributes table. But if I use that information to make ellipses, it'll just draw ellipses at those coordinates, but not necessarily encompass the polygons. I'm looking for a more specific application of the "create ellipse" feature in which it draws an ellipse around my polygons.

Comment: As far as I'm aware it is possible to draw manually as mentioned above. Use the table to bring into ArcMap. Creating a bounding box using ellipse in ArcMap I believe is not currently available

Comment: I've updated my answer and added a few more resources and alternatives

Answer (score 3):

You could refer to Esri's documentation [Creating an ellipse feature](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/creating-new-features/creating-an-ellipse-feature.htm)

> The Ellipse tool is used to create ellipse features.
>
> - These steps can be used to create lines or polygons:
>
>   - To create lines, click a line feature template in the Create Features window.
>   - To create polygons, click a polygon feature template in the Create Features window.
> - Click the Ellipse construction tool Ellipse on the Create Features window.
> - Click to place the center of the ellipse, then drag.
> - Click to set the major or minor radius, then drag.
> - You can also right-click or use keyboard shortcuts to enter x,y coordinates, set a direction angle, choose whether the ellipse is constructed from the center or an endpoint, or enter a major or minor radius. The radius is given in map units by default, but you can give the value in other units by specifying a distance units abbreviation with the value that you enter.
>     Click once to finish the ellipse.

Alternatively, you may try as this user [Make a minimum bound ellipse?](https://community.esri.com/thread/57570) suggests, you would need an extension via ArcMap

> the spatial statistics tool "Directional Distribution (Standard Deviational Ellipse)" may help

To add from my comments:

> As far as I'm aware it is possible to draw manually as mentioned above. Use the [table to bring into ArcMap]
>   (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/table-to-ellipse.htm). Creating a bounding box using ellipse in ArcMap I believe is not currently available

Here is an Esri idea page [Minimum bound ellipse](https://community.esri.com/ideas/6118